# MS Access - Update column in one table from another table based on values in a different column

Tags: ms-access

One table (named Zip Table Definition) has 2-digit or 3-digit zips and their corresponding Market area(POD) with sample values as below:

```
Zip    Market Area ID
350    AB_BIR
722    AR_LIT
850    AZ_PHO
T1     AB_CAL
```

Another table (named **Test DB**) has a field named **Origin Zip** with complete zipcodes (5-digit for US zips and 6-digit for Canada zips), and another field named **Origin POD** that will need to be updated from the first table. Basically we will need the first 3-digit of the full zipcode and then use that value to look up the corresponding **Market Area ID** from the first table. If it doesn't return a value, then we will extract the first 2-digit of the full zipcodes and do the lookup.

I tried to use an Update Query with **DLOOKUP** in the **Update To** row (for the first 3 digits scenario only, not sure how to handle the logic to opt for 2-digit if 3-digit doesn't return a value), but there seems to be something wrong with the query as the Run Query status bar fails to complete. Below is my query:

> Field: Origin POD
>
> Table: Test DB
>
> Update To: DLookUp([Zip Table Definition].[Market Area ID],"Zip Table Definition",[Zip Table Definition].[Zip]=Left([Test DB].[Origin Zip],3))

I know it's much easier to handle it in Excel, but I wanted to learn how to use Access. Any insights and alternative solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Best regards.

Comment: That DLookup syntax is a mess. Expression will need conditional that looks at length of full zip to determine whether to extract 2 or 3 digits. Build query to calc a field that does the extract. Then build another query that joins to the Definition table.

Comment: Really no need to duplicate data into second table. Just calculate when needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to duplicate data into second table and use DLookup:

`Update To: DLookUp("[Market Area ID]", "Zip Table Definition", "Zip='" & Left([Origin Zip], IIf(Len([Origin Zip])=5,3,2)) & "'")`